# how to starred / unstarred message using ajax and classic asp without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am developing message box in classic asp.
I want to implement starred/unstarred functionality (like yahoo mail, gmail mailbox).

I have googled but not found code or help for above written. Please help me to get solution.

Comment: please show us the code or something you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Well I suggest you learn jQuery first: http://www.jquery.com

Then learn how to use Ajax in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Granted you know how to use Classic asp, you would make a page that returns a JSON object for your ajax call

Hope this helps

Comment: @RealWorldCoder....you are right but it will take time to learn. if code is given then it will be easier to implement not for me but many who are looking for this kinda solution. any how i have written two pages for updating db but its refreshing page.

Comment: Then hire someone to code it for you. We are here to help, not work for you.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder...i didn't say that you work for me, did i?...if you are not interested then dont write comment but dont comment like what you written.